# Crear directorio con PHP para otro dominio

Tags: php, cpanel

estoy tratando de crear un directorio con el comando **mkdir** en php, el problema es que este comando solo funciona en el proyecto local en el que estoy trabajando, mi pregunta es:

¿Cómo puedo crear una carpeta en otro dominio diferente al que estoy trabajando?

```
<?php
mkdir("subdomain.domain.com/modelo", 0700);
?>
```

He intentado así pero no me funciona, ¿podrían ayudarme? gracias

Comment: Si, estoy utilizando un comando para crear un subdominio, luego de esto debo crear las carpetas que se utlizarán en el proyecto, todo esto con php, lo de crear el subdominio ya lo tengo resuelto, pero esta última parte no me quiere funcionar

Comment: No me conecto, solo lo creo y listo

Comment: esto es php. no podes trabajar en otro lado, ya que todo lo que es php se ejecuta en el servidor, no en otra maquina. tal vez podrias aclarar tu escenario?

Comment: Suponiendo que estas trabajando en el dominio, para poder crear el archivo, debes darle la ruta del servidor, no el dominio en sí. - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9358779/create-directory-using-php-uploading-files-on-another-domain-account

Comment: Emmm si, tengo un proyecto en el cual puedo crear subdominios con php, lo que quiero es que al crear ese subdominio pueda también crear las carpetas que conciernen a ese subdominio, es como crear una pagina desde otra pagina

Comment: Excorpion, pero es para crearla en un dominio diferente

Comment: Por eso te decía, primero debes conectarte de algún modo a ese dominio. Conexión FTP o algún otro método, por que como bien dice gbianchi, no puedes trabajar en otro lado de ese modo.

Comment: Ah ok, sabes hacerlo?

Comment: Ehh sí, es como conectarse a un servidor, pero te conectas al "cpanel" del dominio a través de una cuenta FTP. Para ello debes crear un usuario FTP el cual asignarás al dominio al cuál te conectarás.

Comment: Podríamos hablar por discord algo así? para que me ayudes

Comment: O puedes meterte al chat de Stack Overflow en Español

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117419/discussion-between-noe-munoz-and-excorpion).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**considerando que:**
el Servidor A es tu servidor primario con X dominio.
el Servidor B es tu servidor secundario con Z Dominio.

> Es casi imposible. todas las iteraciones de php para escribir (Crear
> Archivos y Directorios) son instrucciones que solo tienen acceso al File System Local y el Usuario que ejecuta los servicios Web relacionados debe tener permisos de escritura y ejecucion; la única forma de hacerlo es mediante `FTP`.

https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.ftp-mkdir.php

```
<?php

$dir = 'www';

// establecer una conexión básica
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);

// iniciar sesión con nombre de usuario y contraseña
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);

// intentar crear el directorio $dir
if (ftp_mkdir($conn_id, $dir)) {
 echo "creado con éxito $dir\n";
} else {
 echo "Ha habido un problema durante la creación de $dir\n";
}

// close the connection
ftp_close($conn_id);
?>
```

la otra forma que existe es Mediante Consumir servicios:
esto implica que necesitas un script php en el servidor X que le envié los datos al Servidor Z y tambien un script php que brinde el servicio de recibir los datos y ejecutar localmente la instruccion, en este caso crear el directorio con el nombre que recibio en el consumo del servicio…

https://phppot.com/php/php-restful-web-service/